# Xcode - AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h file not found

Tags: xcode, audiotoolbox

I'm getting started with Xcode and a i'm studying the way to play sound. I have implemented a small project that play a sound using AudioToolbox framework. Everything was fine: i could Build and run normally, the application also functioned normal but today when i reopen the project i have this bug " file not found". It's strange, i didn't modify anything in my project, the framework was linked in my project too. Anyone has the same problem like me?

Answer (score 0):

First try to clean your project by going to the menu bar (the very top) under "Product" and click "Clean". If it still doesn't work: go into the Build Phases, delete the frameworks, then re-add them.

Comment: Last thing I can think of is re-installing xcode... maybe you somehow hit delete and removed it from your computer by accident? Worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens when you take an old project and try to build with a new Xcode version, it could bet due to saving ".framework" files locally within your project. Do check the project folder for such files and remove them, and then use the "Build Phases" tab to link the new frameworks.